# iOS Custom Keyboard Extension Bluetooth Access

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, custom-keyboard, cbcentralmanager

I would like to access a bluetooth device from within a `Custom Keyboard Extension`.
However the `CBCentralManager` will always fall into a `.unsupported` state. I enabled `RequestsOpenAccess` in `info.plist > NSExtension`.

Does anyone else faced the same issue?

My code is as follows. It's based on Apples default `Custom Keyboard Extension` target code.

```
class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController {
    @IBOutlet var nextKeyboardButton: UIButton!
    internal var manager: BLManager?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Perform custom UI setup here
        self.nextKeyboardButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        self.nextKeyboardButton.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("Next Keyboard", comment: "Title for 'Next Keyboard' button"), for: [])
        self.nextKeyboardButton.sizeToFit()
        self.nextKeyboardButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.nextKeyboardButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleInputModeList(from:with:)), for: .allTouchEvents)
        self.view.addSubview(self.nextKeyboardButton)
        self.nextKeyboardButton.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        self.nextKeyboardButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        print("> BL - Keyboard")
        manager = BLManager.shared
    }
    
    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        self.nextKeyboardButton.isHidden = !self.needsInputModeSwitchKey
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    }
}
```

With a corresponding `BLManager` object.

```
internal class BLManager: NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    public static var shared: BLManager = BLManager()
    public var manager: CBCentralManager
    
    override init() {
        manager = CBCentralManager(delegate: nil, queue: nil)
        super.init()
        manager.delegate = self
    }
    
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        if central.state == .poweredOn {
            manager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)
        }
        print("> BL \(central.state)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you testing in simulator?

Comment: No, on a real devices (iPhone 12 Pro / iPhone 8). Using the same code inside a regular project, everything is working as expected as well... .

Comment: Well I have faced `.unsupported` when using simulator.